# What is the most efficient way to collect term frequencies for a specific query in Lucene 6?

Tags: lucene

I would like to gather statistics (i.e. frequencies) for a variety of terms provided a query. What is the most efficient approach to do this? Anything besides the obvious "run the query, collect all document, aggregate field values"?